# java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate

Tags: android, ssl, httpurlconnection

On android 4.1.2 i got no errors but android 1.6 generates exception mentioned in topic. I've tested ssl certificate by https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ and it is ok. Full exception message :

> java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Could not validate
>   certificate: current time: Mon Jul 28 14:20:43 GMT+02:00 2014,
>   expiration time: Tue Mar 18 17:43:41 GMT+01:00 2014

Is there possibility that it is caused by android 1.6?

Comment: Bruno and EJP - I think there should be a FAQ that addresses these questions and provides the basic answers. The FAQ should include troubleshooting and how to fix the errors encountered during troubleshooting. With the FAQ in place, we can cite the FAQ rather than digging up an old Question/Answer.

Comment: What is the URL of the server? Or, what is the output of `openssl x509 -in <certificate> -inform PEM -text -noout`?

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue while doing https(secured) connection to a server.

Try Setting the Device Date to the Current Date.

Answer (score 0):

Set the proper system time on my device and it works.

Go to `Settings` > `System` > `Date & Time` > Set it to `Automatic date & time`